# Sample the process of the frontmost application quickly?

Tags: macos, debug

I run a lot of beta and under development software in time-critical situations. I often find that I have to force quit an app and relaunch it quickly to get back on track, but don't have the time to sample the process so I can send it back to the developer in the hopes they might resolve whatever slowed the software to a halt.

Is anyone aware of a way I could quickly sample the front-most process? Possibly via a script bound to a hotkey or something?

edit: I've found the "sample" command, just trying to figure out how to stitch it together in to a script with the front most processes' PID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didn't take long to figure this one out myself. I have the following apple script bound to a hotkey workflow in Alfred. Samples are saved to /tmp/

```
tell application "Finder"
    set appPath to the path to the frontmost application
    set appName to the name of file appPath
    set appName to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in appName) - 1) of appName
end tell
do shell script "sample '" & appName & "'"
```